# jquery dialog opens and all things work but not second time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

my site is in mvc-4, i am opening partial view in dialog. partial view works fine first time, but when i open it second time and so on it opens he dialog but partial view is not working. I think some jquery issue i am doing wrong. In partial view div hover event is not working.

This is my code to open dialog:

```
<div onclick="ShowHistory();">Actions History</div>
function ShowHistory()
{
    myDialog = $("<div> </div>");
    myDialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 1050,
        title: "Title",
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
    });

    myDialog.load("@Url.Action("Method_return_partial_view", new {id = 1 })",
function () {
        myDialog.dialog('open');
    });

}
```

Controller method:

```
[Authorize]
    public PartialViewResult Method_return_partial_view(int id)
    {
        var list = GetHistory(id);
        return PartialView("_partialViewName", list);
    }
```

Edit:

I am also sorting the grid, and grid sorting is done using jquery ajax, it works fine when open first time and controller method for sorting called once, but when i open dialog second time and i click on sorting header then controller methods called with multiple of two, means if click once then call once, if click 2nd time then controller method calls 2 times, if 3rd then calls 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and specify what happens when the dialog **closes** so that it can be reused again. Try this:

```
function ShowHistory()
{
    myDialog = $("<div> </div>");
    myDialog.dialog({
        close: function (event, ui) {
            // remove div with all data and events            
            myDialog.remove();
                },
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 1050,
        title: "Title",
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
    });

    myDialog.load("@Url.Action("Method_return_partial_view", new {id = 1 })",
function () {
        myDialog.dialog('open');
    });    
}
```